# links aren't clickable

Tags: hyperlink

On [this webpage](http://www.rmselectricalcontractors.com/), I can't click the navigation items on the left.

There is no layer laid over the top.  I can't see what is preventing a click.

Comment: You seem to have several code issues starting with your li tags using both id and class- not sure if that works, and the link to one your of images is not right. How much of this coding did you do yourself or is all of it WordPress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a larger screen it works fine. I tried resizing my browser to make the page smaller and there is something overlapping the links:

```
<div id="right">
```

With a screen resolution of 1024x768 this div overlaps the navigation links and prevents you from clicking them.

You can see what I mean in this image. I made the background colour of that DIV to red, so it's easy to see how much it overlaps.

[image]

So, even though the written content doesn't overlap the navigation links, the container does.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.